# Merge two or more graphs using library

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am trying to make a dynamic graph something like as below:
[image]

Y-axis gives no. of users and x axis date range(For continuous graph )
x axis gives release of an algo on that date.(For discontinued graph)

I tried combined charts of highchart [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types) and looked in google charts library.

Is there any way by how i can either directly generate a similar chart or merge two chart types in to one? Preferably using high charts or google graphs.

I guess we can merge two highcharts in to one but I am not very sure about it, also if we can Iam not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You would like to display multiple chart-types in one chart? (Mix Column with line and pie) Or display multiple sets of data in one chart?

Comment: Since I cannot find any graph in highcharts/Googlecharts similar to mine i thought if merging two different types of chart would get me a solution then why not do that way, So came up with idea where if possible merge 2 charts. Foe example, Area chart and line chart(Where area chart will give me no. of users on each date and line chart giving algorithm changes/update on that date).

Comment: The short answer is yes.  The full answer will depend on more specific questions... Highcharts can plot values like in your example in a couple of different ways.  You don't need to "merge two charts", you just need to plot multiple series of different types on your chart...

Comment: This [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) should be helpful. It's using separate axes for each of the series. And series can have different types (column, area, line etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you said "Preferably using high charts or google graphs", but I want to point out that this can be done very easily in [C3.js](http://www.c3js.org) using the "types" parameter to specify the graph type for each data item.

Demo: http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using plot bands to indicate release dates and types. You can dynamically add them using the `addPlotBand()` method (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand). They would then overlay your "run of the mill" line chart showing number of users over time.

Assuming you have data that can distinguish between the release types, you could write code that adds a plot band of the desired color at the specific points on the x-axis.

I'd suggest making the plot bands have a `from` and `to` value thin enough (say, one interval or one date's worth) so it shows up as the thin stripes in your example.

You'd need to add a manual legend to show users what those colors mean, since plot bands wouldn't automatically show up in a Highcharts legend.

I hope this helps!